# JavaScript removeChild not working

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am using this JavaScript code to remove a couple elements from the page, but it's not working. When I inspect the code with Opera Dragonfly it says something like:

```
Uncaught exception: Error: WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ERR
```

and points to the file and function name.

The weird thing is that I use the exact same code in another function on the same page and it works without problem. The code is very small and simple:

```
var docBody = document.getElementById("body");
if(document.getElementById("marginDiv")){
  docBody.removeChild("marginDiv");
}
```

Both `body` and `marginDiv` exist on the page. My goal is to make the thumbnails disappear when one clicks the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
docBody.removeChild(document.getElementById("marginDiv"));
```

Comment: This worked. Im sure the other answers would work too, but i guess i will choose this because it's the shortest. :)

Comment: The other answer is in fact a lot shorter!

Comment: The original statement minus the quotes should work fine... docBody.removeChild(marginDiv);

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to remove a string. A string is hardly an HTML element. You're also relying on `marginDiv` being a direct child of `body`, which may not be the case.

Instead, try this:

```
var remove = document.getElementById('marginDiv');
if( remove) remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
```

Comment: Or you can do `document.getElementById("marginDiv").remove()`

Comment: Since chrome 19 I think. It's in DOM4

Comment: Both functions are children of body because that's where i create them, using this code:

var marginDiv = document.createElement("div");
  marginDiv.setAttribute("id", "marginDiv");
  docBody.appendChild(marginDiv);

The code is working in another script, for example when you click twice on a button, the thumbnail list gets deleted and created again. Before i used this code to delete it, it used to create a new list whenever i clicked a button. If im doing it wrong, shouldn't it not work at all?

sry for messed up code, i dont know how to write it cleanly

Answer (score 1):

`removeChild` needs a reference to a DOM element, not a string. Try this:

```
var docBody = document.getElementById("body");
var marginDiv = document.getElementById("marginDiv");

if(marginDiv)){
docBody.removeChild(marginDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(document.getElementById("marginDiv")){
  docBody.removeChild("marginDiv");
}
```

you have to check if specified element exist `marginDiv` exist, then `removechild(...)`